# How do I change the Java Security level?

Tags: security, solaris, java, certificates

We've got an ancient (internal use only) self-signed app that refuses to run now with the changes to the JRE.  Working on getting a code signing certificate and rebuilding it, but that's horribly slow going (been going back and forth with the certificate authority for over a week now and still don't have our cert).

I need to get this app back up and running ASAP.  On Windows we've been able to temporarily drop the security level to "medium" to get us by until the cert/rebuild happens.  How do I go about doing the same on our Solaris machines?  Preferably globally (since I'll want to kick the security back up to high as soon and as easily as possible when the program is updated), but per user would also be fine.  Or, if there's a way to insert an exception for just our site for now?

Comment: Ugly temporary workaround for anyone else stuck in this situation.  You can write a shell script to use wget to pull the jar (and resources if you have any) local, then execute it with "java -jar filename".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please don't set the security level to Medium!  This is a battle I've been fighting; there's no need to do this.  [Just specify the URL](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml) (See "Workaround").
2. This is a good thing.  It's requiring legitimately signed certs and a [permissions manifest attribute](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml) (See "Cause") ([Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/manifest.html)).
3. If you aren't aware, there are ways to push out this config uniformly by doing [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/properties.html) (Or more succinctly, [this](http://maxmahem.net/wp/java-update-7u51-security-issues/)).